# Force rstudio to use browser instead of viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

Consider either function which (for rstudio) will open something in the viewer if `y = TRUE` and in your browser if `y = FALSE`. You can force the `whatever` to open in your browser via `options(viewer = NULL)` (and then you need to reset to before), but I can't get this to work inside functions using the normal `on.exit` approach. Tested on windows and osx.

```
f <- function(x, y = TRUE) {
  if (y) {
    oo <- getOption('viewer')
    on.exit(options(viewer = oo))
    options(viewer = NULL)
  } else options(viewer = NULL)
  print(getOption('viewer'))
  DT::datatable(x)
}

g <- function(x, y = TRUE) {
  if (y) {
    oo <- getOption('viewer')
    on.exit(options(viewer = oo))
    options(viewer = NULL)
  } else options(viewer = NULL)
  print(getOption('viewer'))
  htmlTable::htmlTable(x)
}

## in rstudio, returns the viewer function
getOption('viewer')
# function (url, height = NULL) 
# ...

## opens in viewer despite `options(viewer = NULL)`
g(mtcars)
# NULL

## again returns the function, ie, reset my options to before g call successfully
getOption('viewer')
# function (url, height = NULL) 
# ...

## opens in browser but leaves `options(viewer = NULL)` after exiting
g(mtcars, FALSE)
# NULL

getOption('viewer')
# NULL
```

It seems like the viewer isn't respecting my options within the function environment with either just some html (`g`) or a widget (`f`). I thought both would use `viewer = NULL` inside the function and return my options the way they were upon exiting so that I can control where I want to view the result.

Or is there a better way of doing this for both html and widgets? I have tried the `options` argument in `DT::datatable` to no avail, but this wouldn't help for the `htmlTable::htmlTable` case.

The only other approach I can think of is to write all the code to a temp file and use `if (rstudio) rstudio::viewer(tempfile) else browseURL(tempfile)` which I think is a lot of work for something seemingly so straight-forward.

Comment: extra points if someone can look at my edit history and tell me how the diff knows I deleted the same characters in two different ways

Comment: I sent up the "Bat Signal" to Ushey. Hopefully he's watching the clouds in Seattle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although this isn't a fix, I think it illustrates what's going on. Try adding a `Sys.sleep()` call in the `on.exit()` handler:

```
f <- function(x) {
  viewer <- getOption("viewer")
  on.exit({
    print("Restoring viewer...")
    Sys.sleep(3)
    options(viewer = viewer)
  }, add = TRUE)
  options(viewer = NULL)
  DT::datatable(x)
}

## opens in viewer despite `options(viewer = NULL)`
f(mtcars)
```

You'll notice that RStudio doesn't 'decide' what to do with the result of `DT::datatable()` call until *after* the `on.exit()` handler has finished execution. This means that, by the time RStudio wants to figure out to do with the result, the viewer has already been restored! Odds are, RStudio waits until R is no longer 'busy' to decide how to display the resulting content, and by then is too late for temporary changes to the `viewer` option.

Note that this doesn't explain the `htmlTable` behaviour. My best guess is that there is some kind of race condition going on; the lost `viewer` option seems to go away with strategically placed `Sys.sleep()` calls...

Unfortunately, working around this means avoiding the use of `on.exit()` call -- unless we can figure out to handle this in RStudio, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way you could get this functionality by writing the code to a temporary file and using `browseURL` or whatever you like.

The gist of both `f` and `g` are the same, so you could have one function to handle any type of html code or widget I suppose. And probably widgets need to be `selfcontained = TRUE`.

```
f <- function(x, y = TRUE) {
  x <- if ((inherits(x, 'iplot'))) x else DT::datatable(x)
  if (!y) {
    htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.html')
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(x, htmlFile, selfcontained = TRUE)
    utils::browseURL(htmlFile)
  } else x
}

g <- function(x, y = TRUE) {
  x <- htmlTable::htmlTable(x)
  if (!y) {
    htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.html')
    writeLines(x, con = htmlFile)
    utils::browseURL(htmlFile)
  } else x
}

## opens in viewer
g(mtcars)
## opens in browser
g(mtcars, FALSE)

## same for widgets
f(mtcars)
f(mtcars, FALSE)

f(qtlcharts::iplot(1:5, 1:5), FALSE)

## and my options haven't changed
getOption('viewer')
# function (url, height = NULL) 
# ...
```

Side note that this is actually the proper way to have `htmlTable::htmlTable` use a different viewer, but `g` should work for any html.

```
library('htmlTable')
print(htmlTable(mtcars), useViewer = utils::browseURL)
```