# Force RStudio to plot in Viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

My plots tab doesn't work - so I am trying to display the output of `ggplot` in the Viewer tab.

This has been accomplished for printing HTML tables: [Force rstudio to use browser instead of viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312891/force-rstudio-to-use-browser-instead-of-viewer). Can this be done for plots?

```
library(ggplot2)
gg.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Is there a method to print to viewer?

Comment: If the plot pane isn't working, you could direct the plot to an external window with th x11() function as in `library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
x11()
ggplot(data = iris, aes(Petal.Length)) + geom_histogram()`

Comment: I'm getting an error `Error: unexpected symbol in "x11() ggplot` running that piece of code. I can print to PDF but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: `x11()` and `ggplot(...)` are separate commands and need to be run on separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a comment, but couldn't get the formatting right, so I'm making it an answer. This code will create a new window to put your plot in.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
x11() # creates the new window
ggplot(data = iris, aes(Petal.Length)) + geom_histogram()
dev.off() # closes the window when you're done with it
```

Comment: I can't get the `x11()` function to work. Do you know of a method to output to Viewer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I would guess you would need to save the image and then open it in the viewer, but I don't have much basis for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is what the viewer pane was designed for. [This](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) article from Ian Pylvainen suggests that this pane is *exclusively* for web content. Unless you were attempting to visualise your plots in an HTML instance (produced from Markdown, Shiny, htmlwidgets, etc.), I would not recommend Rstudio's Viewer as a viable solution.

To continue with @Joseph Clark John's recommendation, using the variety of other devices R offers might be of use to you. Their recommendation to use `x11()` is specific to linux distributions so if using Windows or MacOs, you could produce another window using the `windows()` or `quartz()` commands, respectively (See documentation for all relevant [devices](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/Devices.html)).

This post touches on this:
   [Make R Studio plots only show up in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534643/make-r-studio-plots-only-show-up-in-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `plotly::ggplotly()` to display a ggplot in the Viewer pane:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data(iris)
plotObj <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(Petal.Length)) + geom_histogram()
plotly::ggplotly(plotObj)
```